# Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, android, react-native, expo

- I build android for a react native project in Ubuntu. And I got this error.
  [image]

How can I fix this error? Please help me. Thank you first.

Answer (score 8):

I tried a ton of ways. Finally, I find out where is the problem from. It's come from `javac`, I don't have a Java compiler yet.
I reinstall Java follow this instruction:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-22-04

Boom, the problem is resolved. I hope this help other people who have the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps!

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17609#issuecomment-1189770234

Try upgrading your gradle version using the upgrade assistant or use the instructions in the mentioned link above.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just install: Java-11-openjdk-amd64

But in your case install: Java-17-openjdk-amd64

Answer (score 0):

While `java -version` and `echo $JAVA_HOME` showed the correct OpenJDK version managed by jenv, the React Native build was still failing. This indicated an incompatibility likely between how jenv managed the JDK and how Gradle/React Native expected it to be configured.

Resolving this, I reinstalled OpenJDK manually and set the environment variables directly without using jenv. This circumvented any potential issues and allowed the build to succeed, confirming it was an interaction problem rather than an invalid JDK setup.

Going forward, when seeing similar errors despite a correct JDK configuration via jenv, I will investigate possible jenv-specific incompatibilities with the build tools used.